# how to call notifyDataSetChanged after deleting listItem

Tags: android

My `fragment` class:

```
        ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter adapter = new ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.adapter_view_services_list_in_new_order , servicesArrayList);
        servicesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In `ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter`  class:

```
    class ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ServicesList>
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    deleteServiceBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int id = servicesList.get(position).getId();
                servicesList.remove(position);
                //MARK
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "pressed: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

How to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in MARK?
First idea is to create interface in `ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter` class.

```
    public interface ServicesListAdapterListener {
        void updateServicesListAfterDeleting(ServicesList servicesList);
    }
```

But it won't work because I don't have method `onAttach` in my adapter. How to solve?
I ran into another problem:[image]
Red button is `deleteServiceBtn` on btn press item disappears but total sum no recounted. Field Total `sum(Netto)`: and other fields below is from first class. And this is code how I calculate total sum:

```
        adapter = new ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_view_services_list_in_new_order , servicesArrayList);
        servicesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < servicesArrayList.size(); i++) {
          sum += servicesArrayList.get(i).getServiceTotalPrice();
        }
        totalPriceForAllServices.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

How to update totalPriceForAllServices.setText from my ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter class?

Answer (score 1):

There is another operator called `notifyItemRemoved()` in case of deletion from `RecyclerView` but please make sure you have deleted the item from data source also.

```
 int id = servicesList.get(position).getId();
 servicesList.remove(position);
 notifyDataSetChange()
 Toast.makeText(mContext, "pressed: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Edit**: Since you have extended `ArrayAdapter` there is no `notifyItemRemoved()` but you can use `remove(T object)` method described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#remove(T)).

Comment: I have two different class. I cant call adapter.(methods) because I don't have adapter in ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter class. Oh wait. I just simply could call notifyDataSetChanged(); in MARK. omg

Comment: if you are inside the adapter call the method directly

Answer (score 0):

To notify the list adapter that the dataset has been modified, you can do:

```
((ServicesListInNewOrderAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()
```

In case of remove you can use `notifyItemRemoved(item)` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

For particular item position want to  change to call
notifyItemRemoved(item)
You want to change all list item 
notifyDataSetChanged();